# Worklight 6.2 web view not opening first time in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiwebview, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a ViewController inherited be CDVViewController. Now when I am trying to launch the viewController it dismiss it automatically. Then I have again launch the same viewController and then it works fine. Could anybody let me know why is this happening or whats the fix for the same. 
Worklight Version : 6.2
iOS : 7.1
iphone: 5s

AppDelegate

```
//
//  MyAppDelegate.h
//
//

#import "WLAppDelegate.h"
#import "WL.h"

@interface MyAppDelegate : WLAppDelegate <WLInitWebFrameworkDelegate> {

@end

//
//  MyAppDelegate.m
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WLWebFrameworkInitResult.h"
#import "Cordova/CDVViewController.h"

@implementation Compatibility50ViewController
/**
 In iOS 5 and earlier, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode only. To support additional orientations, you must override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any orientations your subclass supports.
 */
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    BOOL result = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    [[WL sharedInstance] showSplashScreen];    
    [[WL sharedInstance] initializeWebFrameworkWithDelegate:self];
  // Launched the ViewContorller Here
    return result;
}

// This method is called after the WL web framework initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.
-(void)wlInitWebFrameworkDidCompleteWithResult:(WLWebFrameworkInitResult *)result {
    if ([result statusCode] == WLWebFrameworkInitResultSuccess) {
        [self wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully];
    } else {
        [self wlInitDidFailWithResult:result];
    }
}

-(void)wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully {
[[WL sharedInstance] hideSplashScreen];
}

-(void)wlInitDidFailWithResult:(WLWebFrameworkInitResult *)result
{
}

@end
```

// ViewContorller

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "WL.h"

@interface KHybridBaseViewController : CDVViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

#import "KHybridBaseViewController.h"

@implementation KHybridBaseViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
        self.wwwFolderName = @"www/default";
    self.startPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath]];

  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - WebView Delegate
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView
     shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return [super webView:theWebView
     shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                 navigationType:navigationType];
}

@end
```

Also I am adding the log that I get when I launch the screen first time

```
> 2014-07-31 12:09:20.164 sample[16948:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES,
> App: YES 2014-07-31 12:09:20.167 sample[16948:60b] Unlimited access to
> network resources 2014-07-31 12:09:20.168 sample[16948:6e0f] [DEBUG]
> [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:117 :: START 2014-07-31
> 12:09:20.244 sample[16948:60b] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.119984ms 2014-07-31
> 12:09:20.245 sample[16948:60b] [CDVTimer][push] 0.069976ms 2014-07-31
> 12:09:20.245 sample[16948:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup]
> 0.966966ms 2014-07-31 12:09:20.263 sample[16948:60b] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl _wlInitDidCompleteWithResult:] in WLImpl.m:97 :: END 2014-07-31 12:09:20.269 sample[16948:60b]
> worklight:///Users/rahul.singh1/Library/Application Support/iPhone
> Simulator/7.1/Applications/50D15A9F-732F-4EAE-9463-6F3F0366002B/sample.app/www/default/index.html
> 2014-07-31 12:09:20.271 sample[16948:60b] Resetting plugins due to page
> load. 2014-07-31 12:09:20.914 sample[16948:60b] GET_BAG_ITEMS
> 2014-07-31 12:09:20.915 sample[16948:2d07] Multi-tasking -> Device:
> YES, App: YES 2014-07-31 12:09:20.917 sample[16948:2d07] Unlimited
> access to network resources 2014-07-31 12:09:20.930 sample[16948:60b]
> log1 2014-07-31 12:09:20.944 sample[16948:60b] Failed to load webpage
> with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain
> error -999.) 2014-07-31 12:09:20.946 sample[16948:2d07] [WARN] [NONE]
> Initialization option 'connectOnStartup' is deprecated. Use
> WL.Client.connect() to connect to the Worklight Server. 2014-07-31
> 12:09:20.970 sample[16948:5613] [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event
> dispatched 2014-07-31 12:09:20.972 sample[16948:6d0b] [WARN] [NONE]
> Initialization options 'enableLogger' and 'logger' are deprecated. Use
> WL.Logger.config to set logger behavior. 2014-07-31 12:09:20.972
> sample[16948:8103] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started 2014-07-31
> 12:09:20.974 sample[16948:8203] [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null
> 2014-07-31 12:09:20.975 sample[16948:1303] [WARN] [NONE] Initialization
> option 'analytics' is deprecated. Use WL.Analytics.enable/disable to
> set analytics data capture. 2014-07-31 12:09:20.975 sample[16948:8303]
> [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {} 2014-07-31 12:09:20.976
> sample[16948:8703] [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess
> 2014-07-31 12:09:20.977 sample[16948:8803] [DEBUG] [NONE] after:
> initOptions.onSuccess 2014-07-31 12:09:20.977 sample[16948:8a03]
> [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success 2014-07-31 12:09:20.977
> sample[16948:8903] [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause event handler 
> 2014-07-31 12:09:21.089 sample[16948:60b] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
> initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. Please do let me know where am I doing wrong or what needs to be fixed.

Comment: There has been recent fixes what exact version are you using ?

Comment: I am using IBM Worklight Studio V6.2.0.0. Is there any updated version or this is the latest? Why is it happening that it doesn't load the first time and then it works fine then after. Is it something related to loading of html and javascript on the webview?

Comment: @RahulSingh, can you provide this in the form of a functioning Xcode project we can run? Remove what we should not see, or create a demo project showing only the problem...

Comment: This likely happens because you are trying to load resources before the the framework successfully initialized; move the preparation of the resources you want to load (the start page) to your other view controller.

Comment: @Idan Adar: I have updated the code. Still the same issue. I have found the bug.If I go to the WWW folder and look for initOptions.js and comment  `if (window.addEventListener) {
 window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
 window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
}` line.I shall run in first instance.Could you check and let me know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is not fully clear to me.
Whether you want this View Controller to be presented before Worklight's, or afterwards by tapping a button or alike.

You may want to look at the sample project provided in the following blog post:
[Integrating a Worklight-based iOS app with Xcode Storyboard](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/integrating_a_worklight_based_ios_app_with_xcode_storyboard?lang=en)

While the blog post talks about how to do so in the context of Xcode Storyboard, this is not a requirement. It could be a XIB as well...

The blog shows how to "re-order" the launch sequence so that it will be one with the Storyboard and be able to traverse from the Cordova View Controller (containing the Web View) to other View Controllers.